# Processing dataframe based on two conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a file for processing. Looks like:

```
       1       0     2      3
   0 name1 sample1 typeA1 type1
   1 name2 sample2 typeA2 type2
   2 name3 sample3 typeA3 type3
   3 name4 sample4 typeA4 type4
```

In `typeA` and `type` cols I got a few values. 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D'.

What I want to do:

Need to change columns typeA and type based on their values. Example:

`if in typeA[0] is 'D' and in type[0] = 'D'` then `typeA[0] = 'Z' and type[0] = Y`

`if in typeA[0] is 'A' and in type[0] = 'C'` then `typeA[0] = 'Z' and type[0] = Z`

... etc.

I wrote a if else statement and put it into loop, code looks that:

```
for n in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[n,2] == 'D' and df.iloc[n,3] == 'D':
      df.iloc[n,2] = 'Z'
      df.iloc[n,3] = 'Y'
    elif .... etc.
```

I have questions:

** Exist the simplest way to do that using only pandas?**

I found an example like this:

```
data.loc[data.bidder == 'parakeet2004', 'bidderrate'] = 100
```

Where author changing all `bidderrate's` col values to `100`, when in `bidder col` is `"parakeet2004"` value. Without any loop, he changes 3 rows in this case.

I tried to do that (in various ways) for double statement column like in my case but I got only Key Error. Is even possible for more conditions?

And if can someone explain me beyond the main question:  On my case in my loop, am I working on a copy of data frames or on the original object?**

If it's copy, what should I do to work on the original object (I wouldn't waste memory)?

I found some similar questions on SO but no one can handle my problem: C

.head() of my DF:

```
    1           0           2   3
0   Adac44402   samp1       C   D
1   Adac44402   samp341     A   D
2   Adac44402   samp2341    A   C
3   Adac44402   samp221     C   B
4   Adac44402   samp112     C   D
```

​

Comment: Why minus? :C I tried to describe my question in best way :C

Comment: How many matching criteria do you have? You show ['D', 'D']['Z','Y'] and ['A', 'C']['Z', 'Z']   Also, how many rows in your dataframe?

Comment: What is `typeA` and `type` here? They don't relate to either the index or columns of your DF. That's the issue you're facing, because there's nothing stopping you having multiple conditions in `.loc`, but you have no way of pointing to the data that you want to test

Comment: The clearest thing you could do here, not just in the question but actually making the code more maintainable, is to name the columns btw. Once they have a name, it's much easier to understand `.loc` rather than the columns also being numbered, in an order that is different than numerical order

Comment: I have no headers so "typesA" and "types" are on index 2 and 3 (that what im using in if else). I have a key in device doc. saying: when "typeA' is 'A' and "typeB" is 'D' then first type of analyze is holistic, typeA is 'mathematics'. Co I just want to replace symbols to words depends on combinations of symbols.

Comment: And have you noticed that it goes `1 0 2 3` in the default headers? There is nothing stopping you providing custom headers to the data and that is what I was suggesting

Comment: could you show the `.head()` of your dataframe ?

Comment: @J.Doe added to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['name' + str(i) for i in range(1,5)],
                     'B': ['sample' + str(i) for i in range(1,5)],
                     'C': ['DtypeA', 'typeA', 'DtypeA', 'typeA',],
                     'D': ['typeA', 'DtypeD', 'DtypeD', 'typeD']})
```

which is like

```
       A        B       C       D
0  name1  sample1  DtypeA   typeA
1  name2  sample2   typeA  DtypeD
2  name3  sample3  DtypeA  DtypeD
3  name4  sample4   typeA   typeD
```

First you need to index all rows that satisfy your conditions (here only the third line satisfies the condition)

```
condition = ((temp['C'].str[0] == 'D') & (temp['D'].str[0] == 'D'))
```

Then by indexing them, you can change their values

```
temp.loc[condition, 'C'] = 'Z' + temp.loc[condition, 'C'].str[1:]
```

which gives

```
       A        B       C       D
0  name1  sample1  DtypeA   typeA
1  name2  sample2   typeA  DtypeD
2  name3  sample3  ZtypeA  DtypeD
3  name4  sample4   typeA   typeD
```

Comment: A really nice answer but I _suspect_ that you've taken the values too literally and started string operations on them. We could do with some clarification from the OP

Answer (score 1):

Create helper DataFrame with old and new values, add them to original DataFrame by `merge` with left join and repalce by `fillna` missing values:

```
L = [('D','D','Z','Y'), ('A','C','Z','Z')]
cols = ['2','3']

#changed columns to strings for correct match
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
cols1 = [f'{a}_' for a in cols]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols  + cols1)
print (df1)
   2  3 2_ 3_
0  D  D  Z  Y
1  A  C  Z  Z

df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
df[cols1] = df[cols1].fillna(df[cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_'))
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: x.rstrip('_'))
print (df)
           1         0  2  3
0  Adac44402     samp1  C  D
1  Adac44402   samp341  A  D
2  Adac44402  samp2341  Z  Z
3  Adac44402   samp221  C  B
4  Adac44402   samp112  C  D
```

Another idea is use loop with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and list for original with replacement values in tuples:

```
L = [('D','D','Z','Y'), ('A','C','Z','Z')]

for x in L:
    df.loc[(df[2] == x[0]) & (df[3] == x[1]), [2,3]] = [x[2], x[3]]

print (df)
           1         0  2  3
0  Adac44402     samp1  C  D
1  Adac44402   samp341  A  D
2  Adac44402  samp2341  Z  Z
3  Adac44402   samp221  C  B
4  Adac44402   samp112  C  D
```

Comment: @Artur - sure, it loop by each list of tuples and seelct by position, x[0] seelct first value of tuple, similar x[1] for second value and x[3] for forth.